# Streaming online audio - plays the very first audio only

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have two activity:

1. MediaPlayer_Activity (display the control like play,pause,stop,next....)
2. MediaPlayerPlayList_Acitivty (to display all the available songs)

I am streaming an on-line audio file by loading all the songs URL in the `ArrayList` called `SongsList` and play one by one or user can select from the `MediaPlayerPlayList_Acitivty`(a different activity that show all the songs) and play whatever the song...the `MediaPlayerPlayList_Acitivty` is passing the correct songIndex and I confirmed by doing the debuging the code.

the problem: it only playing the very first song which is the songIndex(0) regardless which song I select from the `MediaPlayerPlayList_Acitivty` it plays the very first song.

As soon as I select a new song from the `MediaPlayerPlayList_Acitivty` I get the error which I paste below and also I have paste the core code that I am using for this media player.

I spent very good amount of time debugging the code but no avail.

logCat:

```
03-18 07:15:52.338: E/MediaPlayer(998): error (1, -1004)
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998):  at net.website.player.MediaPlayer_Activity.playSong(MediaPlayer_Activity.java:341)
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998):  at net.website.player.MediaPlayer_Activity.onActivityResult(MediaPlayer_Activity.java:325)
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
    03-18 07:15:52.338: W/System.err(998):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: W/System.err(998):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: W/System.err(998):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: W/System.err(998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: W/System.err(998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: W/System.err(998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: W/System.err(998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: W/System.err(998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: W/System.err(998):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:52.348: E/MediaPlayer(998): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
    03-18 07:15:52.348: E/MediaPlayer(998): error (-38, 0)
    03-18 07:15:52.458: E/MediaPlayer(998): Error (-38,0)
    03-18 07:15:52.458: D/onCompletion(998): 2
    03-18 07:15:52.458: D/playSong(998): 5
    03-18 07:15:53.058: E/MediaPlayer(998): error (1, -1004)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at net.website.player.MediaPlayer_Activity.playSong(MediaPlayer_Activity.java:341)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at net.website.player.MediaPlayer_Activity.onCompletion(MediaPlayer_Activity.java:449)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1344)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    03-18 07:15:53.058: W/System.err(998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    03-18 07:15:53.068: W/System.err(998):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:53.218: E/MediaPlayer(998): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
    03-18 07:15:53.218: E/MediaPlayer(998): error (-38, 0)
    03-18 07:15:53.218: E/MediaPlayer(998): Error (-38,0)
    03-18 07:15:53.218: D/onCompletion(998): 3
    03-18 07:15:53.228: D/playSong(998): 5
    03-18 07:15:53.828: E/MediaPlayer(998): error (1, -1004)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at net.website.player.MediaPlayer_Activity.playSong(MediaPlayer_Activity.java:341)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at net.website.player.MediaPlayer_Activity.onCompletion(MediaPlayer_Activity.java:449)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1344)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    03-18 07:15:53.828: W/System.err(998):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-18 07:15:53.908: E/MediaPlayer(998): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
    03-18 07:15:53.908: E/MediaPlayer(998): error (-38, 0)
    03-18 07:15:53.918: E/MediaPlayer(998): Error (-38,0)
```

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Mediaplayer
mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d("onPrepared", "mp.start()");
    mp.start();
    }
});
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.d("onCompletion", ""+currentSongIndex);
        // check for repeat is ON or OFF
        if(isRepeat){
            // repeat is on play same song again
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else if(isShuffle){
            // shuffle is on - play a random song
            Random rand = new Random();
            currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else{
            // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    } 

public void  playSong(int songIndex){
            // Play song
            //mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                Log.d("playSong", ""+ songsList.size());
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("audio_url"));
                mp.prepare();
                //mp.start(); //
                // Displaying Song title
                String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("title_a");
                songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

                // Changing Button Image to pause image
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

                // set Progress bar values
                songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                songProgressBar.setMax(100);

                // Updating progress bar
                 updateProgressBar();       

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the stack trace the prepare call is failing due to `java.io.IOException`. Is the datasource url correct? The `songsList` list may not have populated correctly?

Comment: you were right, it was returning the correct song index but the audio file was not exists on the server... silly me :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It appears that your app is crashing because of a call to `mp.getDuration()`. My guess is that this is happening in your `updateProgressBar()` method when it is executing at an inopportune time.</strike>

Since you register an `OnCompletionListener`, in your `playSong` method, you should be calling `prepareAsync()` instead of `prepare()`.

**EDIT** Looking closer at the stack trace, it seems that the problem is not happening from within `updateProgressBar()`, but directly from the call to `prepare()` inside `playSong()`. See if switching to `prepareAsync()` changes the behavior.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i did try prepareAsync and it's keep looping meaning that in the mediaplayer activity my song name title changes and it's infinit loop and I have to kill the emulator to stop it.

Comment: @AbuHamzah - That's odd. I don't see where it would be looping. From what I can tell, you only advance from one song to the next in the onCompletion, which should only execute when a song finishes. Have you identified the sequence of events in the loop?